# Apple And Windows On One Machine

Tags: windows, mac-osx, installation

Am planning to start developing Android and Iphone/Ipad applications. Before that i came to realized that developing iOS applications is only possible on Mac Machines. Am looking for ways to have Windows  7 and Mac Software on one laptop for my development projects so that i don't have to buy two different machines.

At the moment i don't know if its possible to install Mac on Windows or vice versa.  I hope there may be a better way to get those two operating systems on one laptop. I decided to ask you guys the best way i can get the two operating systems on one laptop.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is OT here. Please read our [FAQ].

Comment: @SvenW where should i post this question?

Comment: The [FAQ] lists possible alternatives like [SU] or maybe http://apple.stackexchange.com, but you have to check yourself is the question is topical there and has been asked before (very likely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buy a Mac and dual boot (Bootcamp) or virtualise Windows. This is the only legal, reliable solution right now as you can not legally run OSX on anything but Apple hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a little question. With the "dual boot" OR "Windows Virtualisation", can i do anything i want in Windows without any limitations?

Comment: Yes, you can, it runs as a standard windows laptop, the only limitation being the keyboard layout is a little odd, but you can plug in a USB keyboard. With VMWare Fusion you can even install it as dualboot, then load the dualboot partition as a VM, then you can flick between OS' instantaneously by flicking four fingers across the touchpad (I'm not a fanboi, I swear...)